# ExpandableList View from Json

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, expandablelistview, android-json

Currently working on a `ExpandableListView` in android using `RecyclerView`. I have done almost all the thing but somehow I am getting a `NullpointerException` which I can not sort out.Any help will be appreciated.

I  am sharing the code snippet and also the git link

[Used Library](https://github.com/bignerdranch/expandable-recycler-view)

[Code I have tried](https://github.com/avik1990/ExpandableListView)

The app is crasing at this line in the apadter class

```
public DriverScheduleExpandableAdapter(Context mContext, @NonNull 
 List<DriverSchedule.Schedules> parentList) {
            super(parentList);//////**this is where the app is crashing**
            mRecipeList = parentList;
            mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
}
```

Error coming is :

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'java.util.Iterator java.util.List.iterator()' on a null object reference
        at com.bignerdranch.expandablerecyclerview.model.ExpandableWrapper.generateChildItemList(ExpandableWrapper.java:99)
        at com.bignerdranch.expandablerecyclerview.model.ExpandableWrapper.<init>(ExpandableWrapper.java:33)
        at com.bignerdranch.expandablerecyclerview.ExpandableRecyclerAdapter.generateParentWrapper(ExpandableRecyclerAdapter.java:1357)
        at com.bignerdranch.expandablerecyclerview.ExpandableRecyclerAdapter.generateFlattenedParentChildList(ExpandableRecyclerAdapter.java:1326)
        at com.bignerdranch.expandablerecyclerview.ExpandableRecyclerAdapter.<init>(ExpandableRecyclerAdapter.java:120)
        at com.rtstl.expandablelistview.adapter.DriverScheduleExpandableAdapter.<init>(DriverScheduleExpandableAdapter.java:23)
        at com.rtstl.expandablelistview.MainActivity.inflateadapter(MainActivity.java:50)
        at com.rtstl.expandablelistview.MainActivity.initview(MainActivity.java:41)
        at com.rtstl.expandablelistview.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:36)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6357)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1108)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2408)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2515) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:154) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1379) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5571) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:745) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:635)
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
    package com.rtstl.expandablelistview;

    import android.content.Context;
    import android.databinding.DataBindingUtil;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    import com.google.gson.Gson;
    import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken;
    import com.rtstl.expandablelistview.adapter.DriverScheduleAdapter;
    import com.rtstl.expandablelistview.adapter.DriverScheduleExpandableAdapter;
    import com.rtstl.expandablelistview.databinding.ActivityMainBinding;
    import com.rtstl.expandablelistview.model.DriverSchedule;

    import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.InputStream;

    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        ActivityMainBinding binding;
        Context mContext;
        DriverSchedule list_driver;
        DriverScheduleAdapter adapter;
        DriverScheduleExpandableAdapter adapterExp;
        Gson gson;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            mContext=this;
            gson=new Gson();

            initview();
        }

        private void initview() {
            binding= DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main);
            inflateadapter();
        }

        private void inflateadapter() {
            ////for reading file from raw folder otherwise it's not required
            list_driver= gson.fromJson(readFileFromRawDirectory(R.raw.driverschedule), new TypeToken<DriverSchedule>(){}.getType());
            ////////////////////////////////////////
            Toast.makeText(mContext,""+list_driver.getData().getSclist().size(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            adapterExp = new DriverScheduleExpandableAdapter(mContext, list_driver.getData().getSclist());
            binding.rvRecycle.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
            binding.rvRecycle.setAdapter(adapter);
        }


        private String readFileFromRawDirectory(int resourceId){
            InputStream iStream = this.getResources().openRawResource(resourceId);
            ByteArrayOutputStream byteStream = null;
            try {
                byte[] buffer = new byte[iStream.available()];
                iStream.read(buffer);
                byteStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                byteStream.write(buffer);
                byteStream.close();
                iStream.close();

                //inflateadapter();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return byteStream.toString();
        }
    }
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            tools:context=".MainActivity">

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/rv_Recycle"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </layout>
```

**Adapter class**

```
    package com.rtstl.expandablelistview.adapter;

    import android.content.Context;
    import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;

    import com.bignerdranch.expandablerecyclerview.ExpandableRecyclerAdapter;
    import com.rtstl.expandablelistview.R;
    import com.rtstl.expandablelistview.model.DriverSchedule;

    import java.util.List;

    public class DriverScheduleExpandableAdapter extends ExpandableRecyclerAdapter<DriverSchedule.Schedules, DriverSchedule.Alloted_kids, RouteViewHolder, KidViewHolder> {

        private LayoutInflater mInflater;
        private List<DriverSchedule.Schedules> mRecipeList;
        private static final int PARENT_NORMAL = 1;
        private static final int CHILD_NORMAL = 3;

        public DriverScheduleExpandableAdapter(Context mContext, @NonNull List<DriverSchedule.Schedules> parentList) {
            super(parentList);//////**this is where the app is crashing**
            mRecipeList = parentList;
            mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
        }

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public RouteViewHolder onCreateParentViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parentViewGroup, int viewType) {
            View recipeView;
            switch (viewType) {
                default:
                case PARENT_NORMAL:
                    recipeView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.group_item, parentViewGroup, false);
                    break;
            }
            return new RouteViewHolder(recipeView);
        }

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public KidViewHolder onCreateChildViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup childViewGroup, int viewType) {
            View ingredientView;
            switch (viewType) {
                default:
                case CHILD_NORMAL:
                    ingredientView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.child_item, childViewGroup, false);
                    break;
            }
            return new KidViewHolder(ingredientView);
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindParentViewHolder(@NonNull RouteViewHolder parentViewHolder, int parentPosition, @NonNull DriverSchedule.Schedules parent) {
            parentViewHolder.bind(parent);
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindChildViewHolder(@NonNull KidViewHolder childViewHolder, int parentPosition, int childPosition, @NonNull DriverSchedule.Alloted_kids child) {
            childViewHolder.bind(child);
        }

        @Override
        public int getParentViewType(int parentPosition) {
            return PARENT_NORMAL;
        }

        @Override
        public int getChildViewType(int parentPosition, int childPosition) {
            return CHILD_NORMAL;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isParentViewType(int viewType) {
            return viewType == PARENT_NORMAL;
        }
    }
```

**DriverSchedule.java**

```
    package com.rtstl.expandablelistview.model;

    import android.databinding.BaseObservable;

    import com.bignerdranch.expandablerecyclerview.model.Parent;
    import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
    import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

    import java.util.List;

    /**
     * Created by User1 on 09-03-2018.
     */

    public class DriverSchedule extends BaseObservable {

        @SerializedName("status")
        @Expose
        public String status;

        @SerializedName("msg")
        @Expose
        public String msg;

        @SerializedName("data")
        @Expose
        public Data data;

        public String getStatus() {
            return status;
        }

        public void setStatus(String status) {
            this.status = status;
        }

        public String getMsg() {
            return msg;
        }

        public void setMsg(String msg) {
            this.msg = msg;
        }

        public Data getData() {
            return data;
        }

        public void setData(Data data) {
            this.data = data;
        }

        public class Data {

            @SerializedName("schedules")
            @Expose
            List<Schedules> sclist;

            @SerializedName("driver_details")
            @Expose
            Driver_details driver_details;

            public List<Schedules> getSclist() {
                return sclist;
            }

            public void setSclist(List<Schedules> sclist) {
                this.sclist = sclist;
            }

            public Driver_details getDriver_details() {
                return driver_details;
            }

            public void setDriver_details(Driver_details driver_details) {
                this.driver_details = driver_details;
            }
        }

        public class Schedules implements Parent<Alloted_kids> {

            @SerializedName("is_active")
            @Expose
            public String is_active;


            @SerializedName("route_details")
            @Expose
            public Route_details route_details;


            @SerializedName("alloted_kids")
            @Expose
            public List<Alloted_kids> alloted_kids;

            public String getIs_active() {
                return is_active;
            }

            public void setIs_active(String is_active) {
                this.is_active = is_active;
            }

            public Route_details getRoute_details() {
                return route_details;
            }

            public void setRoute_details(Route_details route_details) {
                this.route_details = route_details;
            }

            public List<Alloted_kids> getAlloted_kids() {
                return alloted_kids;
            }

            public void setAlloted_kids(List<Alloted_kids> alloted_kids) {
                this.alloted_kids = alloted_kids;
            }

            @Override
            public List<Alloted_kids> getChildList() {
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean isInitiallyExpanded() {
                return false;
            }
        }

        public class Driver_details {

            @SerializedName("driver_details")
            @Expose
            public Driver_details1 driver_details;

            public Driver_details1 getDriver_details() {
                return driver_details;
            }

            public void setDriver_details(Driver_details1 driver_details) {
                this.driver_details = driver_details;
            }
        }

        public class Route_details {
            @SerializedName("ds_id")
            @Expose
            public String ds_id;

            @SerializedName("kidpool_route_id")
            @Expose
            public String kidpool_route_id;


            public String getDs_id() {
                return ds_id;
            }

            public void setDs_id(String ds_id) {
                this.ds_id = ds_id;
            }

            public String getKidpool_route_id() {
                return kidpool_route_id;
            }

            public void setKidpool_route_id(String kidpool_route_id) {
                this.kidpool_route_id = kidpool_route_id;
            }
        }

        public class Alloted_kids {

            @SerializedName("kid_name")
            @Expose
            public String kid_name;


            @SerializedName("kid_image")
            @Expose
            public String kid_image;

            public String getKid_name() {
                return kid_name;
            }

            public void setKid_name(String kid_name) {
                this.kid_name = kid_name;
            }

            public String getKid_image() {
                return kid_image;
            }

            public void setKid_image(String kid_image) {
                this.kid_image = kid_image;
            }
        }

        public class Driver_details1 {

            @SerializedName("driver_id")
            @Expose
            public String driver_id;


            @SerializedName("driver_name")
            @Expose
            public String driver_name;

            public String getDriver_id() {
                return driver_id;
            }

            public void setDriver_id(String driver_id) {
                this.driver_id = driver_id;
            }

            public String getDriver_name() {
                return driver_name;
            }

            public void setDriver_name(String driver_name) {
                this.driver_name = driver_name;
            }
        }
    }
```

**KidViewHolder.java**

```
    package com.rtstl.expandablelistview.adapter;

    import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    import com.bignerdranch.expandablerecyclerview.ChildViewHolder;
    import com.rtstl.expandablelistview.R;
    import com.rtstl.expandablelistview.model.DriverSchedule;

    class KidViewHolder extends ChildViewHolder{

        private TextView mIngredientTextView;

        public KidViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            mIngredientTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_childname);
        }

        public void bind(@NonNull DriverSchedule.Alloted_kids ingredient) {
            mIngredientTextView.setText(ingredient.getKid_name());
        }
    }
```

**RouteViewHolder.java**

```
    package com.rtstl.expandablelistview.adapter;

    import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
    import android.os.Build;
    import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.animation.RotateAnimation;
    import android.widget.ImageView;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    import com.bignerdranch.expandablerecyclerview.ParentViewHolder;
    import com.rtstl.expandablelistview.R;
    import com.rtstl.expandablelistview.model.DriverSchedule;

    class RouteViewHolder extends ParentViewHolder {

        private static final float INITIAL_POSITION = 0.0f;
        private static final float ROTATED_POSITION = 180f;

        @NonNull
        private final ImageView mArrowExpandImageView;
        private TextView mRecipeTextView;

        public RouteViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            mRecipeTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.group_name);

            mArrowExpandImageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.iv_exp);
        }

        public void bind(@NonNull DriverSchedule.Schedules recipe) {
            mRecipeTextView.setText(recipe.getRoute_details().getKidpool_route_id());
        }

        @SuppressLint("NewApi")
        @Override
        public void setExpanded(boolean expanded) {
            super.setExpanded(expanded);
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
                if (expanded) {
                    mArrowExpandImageView.setRotation(ROTATED_POSITION);
                } else {
                    mArrowExpandImageView.setRotation(INITIAL_POSITION);
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onExpansionToggled(boolean expanded) {
            super.onExpansionToggled(expanded);
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
                RotateAnimation rotateAnimation;
                if (expanded) { // rotate clockwise
                    rotateAnimation = new RotateAnimation(ROTATED_POSITION,
                            INITIAL_POSITION,
                            RotateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f,
                            RotateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
                } else { // rotate counterclockwise
                    rotateAnimation = new RotateAnimation(-1 * ROTATED_POSITION,
                            INITIAL_POSITION,
                            RotateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f,
                            RotateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
                }

                rotateAnimation.setDuration(200);
                rotateAnimation.setFillAfter(true);
                mArrowExpandImageView.startAnimation(rotateAnimation);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: `list_driver.getData().getSclist()` this is null

Comment: no list is not empty

Comment: no this is returning list and i have also checked that the size is 3

Comment: Then post the crash log

Comment: wait a sec posting the log

Comment: posted the error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this issue it seems that your list has some null values
https://github.com/bignerdranch/expandable-recycler-view/issues/321

I ran your code and logged your list you have null values in a list

check this method

```
@Override
 public List<Alloted_kids> getChildList() {
       return null;
 }
```

this method should return non null value this method only causing problem

use return Collections.emptyList(); instead of return null there

Comment: child array is also not empty it have data checked the array size

Comment: see the edit you have nulls in your list not whole item but some child items from list are null

Comment: in your list kid_image child item is null try to give some value and then run it

Comment: also there is null return value in
@Override
        public List<Alloted_kids> getChildList() {
            return null;
        }

Comment: when I am checking the size  Toast.makeText(mContext,""+list_driver.getData().getSclist().get(1).getAlloted_kids().size(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();.It is returning the size perfectly well

Comment: bro you have one null sub item not your whole list so even if you have some null values in your list you will get list size and use log instead of toast

Comment: ohh got it just checking

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171672/discussion-between-mirza-ahmed-baig-and-avik).